# Vue: How to update value onchange inside loop template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have items array and taxes array for an invoice. And I have been trying to update the total sum value when the tax select field is changed but can't think of an exact solution as I can't pass the value to a total value ref or a watcher. Here is my code.

```js
<template>
<div class="cs-container bg-white">
  <ul class="list-none">
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <h2 class="bold text-lg">{{ item.details }}</h2>

      <input type="number" v-model="item.qty"/>

      <select v-model="item.tax_id">
        <option v-for="tax in taxes" :key="tax.id" :value="tax.id">
          {{ tax.name }}
        </option>
      </select>

      <input type="number" v-model="item.rate" />

      <div class="bg-gray-100 p-3 border border-gray-200 mb-3">
        Total:
        <span v-if="item?.tax">
          {{
            itemWithTax(item.rate, item.qty, item.tax.rate)
          }}
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const itemWithTax = (rate, qty, tax_rate) => {
    let total = rate * qty;
    let percent = tax_rate / 100;
    percent = total * percent;
    return total + percent;
};

const items = ref([
    {
        id: 1,
        tax_id: 1,
        details: "Neque offi",
        qty: 3,
        rate: 100,
        tax: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Service Tax",
            rate: 10,
        },
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        tax_id: 1,
        details: "Neque officiis molestiae.",
        qty: 5,
        rate: 310,
        tax: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Service Tax",
            rate: 10,
        },
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        tax_id: 2,
        details: "Totam ab cum.",
        qty: 4,
        rate: 820,
        tax: {
            id: 2,
            name: "GST",
            rate: 17,
        },
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        tax_id: 2,
        details: "Et aut aut.",
        qty: 3,
        rate: 140,
        tax: {
            id: 2,
            name: "GST",
            rate: 17,
        },
    },
]);

const taxes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Service Tax (10%)",
        rate: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "GST (17%)",
        rate: 17,
    },
];
</script>
```

Here is the working Codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-mountain-0fqkyf?file=/src/App.vue

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix is to change the `itemWithTax` function like so

```
const itemWithTax = (rate, qty, tax_id) => {
  const tax_rate = taxes.value.find(({id}) => id === tax_id)?.rate
  let total = rate * qty;
  let percent = tax_rate / 100;
  percent = total * percent;
  return total + percent;
};
```

and call it like

```
itemWithTax(item.rate, item.qty, item.tax_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a computed Property to be able to perform the calculations when the reactive data changes and replace total with the computed property you've created. You can read up more on computed here https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).